# Не поддерждивается удалённое SSH-соединение с сервером на Linux

Tags: linux, windows, сеть, ssh

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что соединиться по ssh не получается, если клиент находится далеко. Я как понял там что-то не пускает. Сам ssh сервер работает через коммутатор (распараллеливатель) D-Link. Компьютер, который присоединен к коммутатору (распараллеливателю), спокойно подключается.

**Чего мне не хватает и что мне надо донастроить?**

Также бы  хотелось подключиться к серверу не только с линукса но и с виндувса.

Вот вывод от клиента (который также подключён к коммутатору (распараллеливателю) )

```
comp@comp0:~$ nmap -Pn -p22 172.16.8.169

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-10-04 11:28 MSK
Nmap scan report for 172.16.8.169
Host is up (0.0015s latency).

PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.35 seconds
comp@comp0:~$ ssh testssh@172.16.8.169
testssh@172.16.8.169's password: 
Linux R2CPU 4.9.11 #32 PREEMPT Mon Sep 17 11:14:03 MSK 2018 armv7l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Thu Oct  3 11:05:20 2019 from 172.16.8.106
Could not chdir to home directory /home/testssh: No such file or directory
$ ls
bin   dev  home     lib     mnt   root  sbin  sys       tmp  var
boot  etc  kononov  lost+found  proc  run   srv   test.lst  usr
$ exit
Connection to 172.16.8.169 closed.
comp@comp0:~$
```

*так и не понял как надо правильно называть коммутатор либо распараллеливатель*

---

В общем из дома попробовал. Вот результат

Попробовал через путти 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же пытался ввести пользователя

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но также не запустилось.

решил проверить. " А вообще соединение с адресом идёт ? "

```
 C:\Users\timob\Desktop\Новая папка\nmap-7.80>nmap.exe  -p 80 example.com
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-10-07 12:07 RTZ 2 (ceia)
Nmap scan report for example.com (93.184.216.34)
Host is up (0.12s latency).

PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.10 seconds

C:\Users\timob\Desktop\Новая папка\nmap-7.80>ping -t 172.16.8.169

Обмен пакетами с 172.16.8.169 по с 32 байтами данных:
Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.

Статистика Ping для 172.16.8.169:
    Пакетов: отправлено = 3, получено = 0, потеряно = 3
    (100% потерь)
Control-C
^C
C:\Users\timob\Desktop\Новая папка\nmap-7.80>nmap.exe  -Pn 22 172.16.8.169
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-10-07 13:06 RTZ 2 (ceia)
Failed to resolve "22".
Stats: 0:00:17 elapsed; 0 hosts completed (1 up), 1 undergoing SYN Stealth Scan
SYN Stealth Scan Timing: About 5.00% done; ETC: 13:10 (0:03:48 remaining)
Stats: 0:00:20 elapsed; 0 hosts completed (1 up), 1 undergoing SYN Stealth Scan
SYN Stealth Scan Timing: About 6.50% done; ETC: 13:10 (0:03:36 remaining)
Stats: 0:00:21 elapsed; 0 hosts completed (1 up), 1 undergoing SYN Stealth Scan
SYN Stealth Scan Timing: About 7.00% done; ETC: 13:10 (0:03:33 remaining)
Stats: 0:00:22 elapsed; 0 hosts completed (1 up), 1 undergoing SYN Stealth Scan
SYN Stealth Scan Timing: About 7.50% done; ETC: 13:10 (0:03:30 remaining)
Stats: 0:00:37 elapsed; 0 hosts completed (1 up), 1 undergoing SYN Stealth Scan
SYN Stealth Scan Timing: About 15.00% done; ETC: 13:10 (0:03:01 remaining)
Stats: 0:00:45 elapsed; 0 hosts completed (1 up), 1 undergoing SYN Stealth Scan
SYN Stealth Scan Timing: About 19.25% done; ETC: 13:10 (0:02:48 remaining)
^C
C:\Users\timob\Desktop\Новая папка\nmap-7.80>nmap.exe  -Pn 2225 172.16.8.169
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-10-07 13:07 RTZ 2 (ceia)
Failed to resolve "2225".
Stats: 0:00:10 elapsed; 0 hosts completed (1 up), 1 undergoing SYN Stealth Scan
SYN Stealth Scan Timing: About 2.00% done; ETC: 13:11 (0:04:05 remaining)
Stats: 0:00:11 elapsed; 0 hosts completed (1 up), 1 undergoing SYN Stealth Scan
SYN Stealth Scan Timing: About 2.50% done; ETC: 13:11 (0:03:54 remaining)
^C
```

**не соединяет :(** Даже почему-то пинг не проходит :(

---

Решил пойти путём *"пробросить порты на белый айпи "* , так как vpn даше не удалось разобраться, это какаето хрень для браузера, а у меня там обычнй  компик с командной строкой.

Узнал свой [айпи](https://2ip.ru/) и прослушал все [открытые порты](https://hidemy.name/ru/ports/)

```
Not shown: 991 filtered ports, 6 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
1723/tcp open  pptp
8181/tcp open  unknown
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 20.30 seconds
```

Такое чувство что порты все закрыты :(

Ну и такой же результат при попытке пробросить порты :

```
root@R2CPU:/# ssh -f -N -R 8181:213.131.7.131 testssh@172.16.8.169
Bad remote forwarding specification '8181:213.131.7.131'
root@R2CPU:/# ssh -f -N -R 2222:213.131.7.131 testssh@172.16.8.169
Bad remote forwarding specification '2222:213.131.7.131'
root@R2CPU:/# ssh -f -N -R 222:213.131.7.131 testssh@172.16.8.169
Bad remote forwarding specification '222:213.131.7.131'
root@R2CPU:/# ssh -f -N -R 2222:213.131.7.131 testssh@172.16.8.169
Bad remote forwarding specification '2222:213.131.7.131'
root@R2CPU:/#
```

Comment: Он называется свитч?..

Comment: @КапитанФлинт свич,  как по мне очень американское слово и я не могу вычленить корень и понять смысл значения.

Comment: по-русски это называется сетевой коммутатор, но в русскоязычной IT-среде как правило используются слова "свитч" и "свечка". Очередное исконно американское слово стало нашим родным русским жаргонизмом.

Comment: Может быть маршрута не хватает от вас к серверу или коммутатору?

Comment: @PotroNik а как это найти , что почитать ??

Comment: Сам ip от вас доступен? Я же правильно понимаю что вы обращаетесь через интернет на сервере который находится за роутером и подключен к коммутатору, если это так, то в зависимости от модели роутера настройть статический маршрут, к примеру если обращение на роутер идет по порту 2225, перенаправлять его на 172.16.8.169 порт 22 и со своего ПК подключаться на ip роутера по порту 2225.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробрось порты на ssh на белый ip или воспользуйся vpn.

Comment: обновил вопрос , такое чувство что псы которые сеть обслуживают всё закрыли на фиг , видимо им придется звонить

Comment: У тебя ип серый, я такие через впн соединяю

Comment: а как  через впн сделать ??? Просто я так и не понял как это сделать,  а поисковик выдаёт только впи-эны для браузеров

Comment: В общем оказалось что роутер компании которая предоставляет , конторе интернет меня никак не пускал что бы я не делал , как только позвонил и написал письмо , они сами мне сделали "окно в мир ". **Это я к тому что мне они сами поянили что я бы не как пробиться не смог.** Думаю только  vpn смог меня спасти, но я до него не успел дотянуться.

Comment: Для Впн надо покупать хостинг, устанавливать, настраивать.

Comment: а как же "месяц бесплатно " или это только рекламный трюк ???

Comment: @timob256 белых впн не видел бесплатных. На серых можно попробовоть состыковаться, но не факт что выйдет. Через брокера Ipv6 можно попробовать

Answer (score 1):

Похоже на клиенте или на сервере "плохой" интернет. Перегруженная таблица коннектов на маршрутизаторе провайдера или по-кривому зароскомнадзорено ядро сети.

На клиенте в `~/.ssh/config` добавьте

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 30
    ServerAliveCountMax 5
```

ServerAliveInterval - поддержание соединения с сервером. Попробуйте поставить значение ещё меньше если мой пример не поможет. Мне помогло.

В PuTTY на этой вкладке можно настроить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо но увы я не могу опробовать ибо я не тот кто хочет подключиться , я всего лишь владелец сервера . А как изменить эти настройки под виндовс ?? (просто до этого я думал что проблема только на сервере может быть ).

Comment: Посмотри в доках, может есть такой же, только другой параметр для сервера.

Comment: PuTTY человек использует, в виндовсе

Comment: добавил картинку с пути

Comment: @eri, я так думаю, проблема больше в том, что адрес сервера фиктивный.

Comment: Ага, через проброс порта. решение для этого пойдёт

Comment: дополнил вопрос.

Comment: @timob256 это уже другой вопрос.) пробрось порты на белый адрес